# ImagePickerController editinfo is nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am calling UIImagePickerController this way:

```
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

and want to get the image that picked with this delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
```

the problem is that the editInfo NSDictionary is equal to nil everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Jump to to definition for the method you're using (CMD +click), it says - "__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED":

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:       
(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_NA,__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_2_0,__IPHONE_3_0);
```

use:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //This if statement is just to make sure we did receive an image and not
    //a video or whatever
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
       UIImage * pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    }
}
```